# Is parsing human-readable data with awk and bash harmful, a bad practice

Tags: bash, parsing, unix, awk

In our C++ class the first module is about bash programming. Our instructor, who often mixes shisms and bashisms and csh compatibility-isms, recently used an example of using awk and bash to get the last friday of the month. He parsed `cal` with a bash script and awk.

Is parsing this data with bash and awk considered bad practice? Should the best way simply be to do math with the Unix timestamp?

Comment: In college a lot of what you do isn't about doing it the 'best' way, it's about explaining a concept and using a simple example problem (which may be easier solved another way) to illustrate that concept. He's teaching you `awk` so naturally he used `awk` to solve the issue at hand.

Comment: awk was created specifically to parse human-readable data. Parsing the output of cal is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. wrt "In our C++ class the first module is about bash programming." Unless the entire module is 1 paragraph on how to invoke the compiler you're in the wrong class!

Comment: Well, it is a class. It will teach you how to make tools, choose tools and use tools. Parsing the irregular output from cal is pretty hard, so it will be a good excersise, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

I would say this is a good example of the power of Unix. Take the output of cal and process it  to get only the information you are interested in. Awk is probably the best tool for this job and the use of cal is clever in my option:

So taking the output:

```
$ cal
      May 2013      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

We know the dates for Friday will be in the sixth column but not every line will have a sixth column. So we want the value of the last no empty entry in the sixth column. With awk I would do:

```
$ cal | awk '$6{date=$6}END{print date}'
31
```

So we know the last Friday on the month is the 31<sup>st</sup>.

The real strange this here is why in your C++ class are you not learning C++?

Comment: `why in your C++ class are you not learning C++?` could not stop laughing... :) +1 for that

Comment: I guess it's because "the first module is about bash programming" (as per question). Perhaps to contrast CSH with C, highlighting the compiler's abilities.

Comment: No, it's to teach people how to use basic linux stuff via sshing into the server. Most of my classmates have never even touched a CLI before. They will have absolutely a lot of trouble finding their .cpp files, and understanding what a "compiler flag" or "return code" is.

Comment: I can see how people might need to interact with the shell to compile and run their C++ programs, but that's hardly a reason to learn shell programming. I thought C++ lived off of the likes of `Makefile`s, `aclocal.m4`, `configure`, not build scripts stitched together with Bash. To each his own. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is very relative.

In the real world, you want to do something clear and maintainable, and using Unix timestamp may or may not be that, depending on the bigger context of the program. Perhaps a different system is consuming the result that doesn't want to learn about Unix timestamps.

For your college class, the point is to learn something, so "best" is something completely different. School isn't always about the quickest solution; sometimes you take detours to get exposed to the landscape you're learning about. Probably the parsing with bash and awk is the best thing in this context, as it exposes you to bash and awk scripting. Lemme tell you, Unix timestamps won't solve all your string processing issues when the rubber hits the road.

(Removed note about the vagueness of your question.)